# How to enable commandlets for SharePoint Web in PowerShell

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, powershell

I am trying to get `$Web.RequestAccessEmail` in the following powershell script. but i don't see the cmdlet 
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You need to get the webs in the 2nd for-each loop.

```
$wa = Get-SPWebApplication $webappurl
foreach ($s in $wa.Sites)
{
$s.Url
    foreach($w in $s.AllWebs)
    {
        write-host "test =" $w.RequestAccessEmail 
    }
}
```